# Updating images (using File ft) within a Grid updates other File fields

Tags: file-uploads, grid, ee3

I'm finding, since updating to EE 3.4.0, that when I have a Grid field of rows, each with a File field (to upload an image), I'm finding that updating one File field is then updating other File fields on the same page (some not even in the Grid field) with the same image. I then switch the other File field back to the image it should be and the first one switches to this one too - it's making it impossible to update entries, and has only been seen since upgrading EE to v3.4.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/22018/FilePicker-callback-methods-stacking-and-being-run-when-they-shouldnt

Will be fixed in EE3.4.1 - relates to a Javascript file messing with the File field